# Multiple Joins between multiple tables

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

I am building a Time off requests tool for work.

I have 3 tables: REQUESTS, COVERED, and MODID.

REQUESTS Has the following fields:

```
ID INT Auto_Increment not null Primary Key
MODID VARCHAR(7) not null
THE_DATE DATE not null
THE_TIME VARCHAR(30) not null
COVERED CHAR(1) not null Default = 'N'
```

COVERED Has the follow fields:

```
ID INT not null Primary Key
CMODID VARCHAR(7) not null
```

Lastly MODID has the following fields:

```
MODID VARCHAR(7) not null Primary Key
MODNAME VARCHAR(40) not null
```

When a time off request is put in REQUESTS populates with ID (auto_increment) the MODID of the mod putting in the TOR THE_DATE the mod needs covere and THE_TIME of their shift.

I have a PHP back end built that enters the above data. The same back end, when someone picks up a shift, adds the REQUESTS.ID to COVERED.ID and the MODID of the mod covering the shift. It then sets REQUESTS.COVERED = "Y" for that specific shift.

I can get a list of all the MODS that have an active time off requests using the following:

```
SELECT M.MODNAME, R.THE_DATE, R.THE_TIME
FROM REQUESTS R
INNER JOIN MODID M ON M.MODID = R.MODID WHERE COVERED = 'N';
```

The problem I am having is I want to get a list of all the mods whose requests is covered the date and time of their requests and the name of the mod that covered the shift EG

Requested MODNAME Date Time Covereing MODNAME

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT M.MODNAME, R.THE_DATE, R.THE_TIME, C.CMODID
FROM REQUESTS R, COVERED C 
INNER JOIN MODID M ON M.MODID = R.MODID 
INNER JOIN MODID M ON M.MODID = C.CMODID
WHERE COVERED = 'N';
```

I know the above MySQL has a lot wrong with it, but I am stuck and don't know what to do.

Here is a DUMP of my MYSQL table
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12531574/TOR_2013-02-22.sql

**EDIT**

**THE CLOSEST I CAN GET**

Using:

```
SELECT R.MODID, R.THE_DATE, R.THE_TIME, C.CMODID
FROM REQUESTS R
INNER JOIN COVERED C ON C.ID = R.ID;
```

Outputs:

```
MODID   THE_DATE    THE_TIME    CMODID
AKH3    2013-02-28  10:00AM - 1:00PM PST    TST3
```

All I want to do with that is change AKH3 (MODID) to the corresponding MODNAME in the MODID table and TST3 (CMODID) to the corresponding MODNAME in the MODID table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only seeking out the ones with coverage, you don't NEED left joins and you should hopefully have FK Constraints in place to keep the mod lookups from breaking. This will give you what you want, with the additional second join of the MODID table giving you the covering mod's name.

```
SELECT M.MODNAME, R.THE_DATE, R.THE_TIME, CM.MODNAME AS `MOD COVERING NAME`
FROM REQUESTS R
JOIN MODID M ON R.MODID = M.MODID
JOIN COVERED C ON C.ID = R.ID
JOIN MODID CM ON CM.MODID = C.CMODID
```

I would highly suggest you change the table structure to store the CMODID to the actual integer ID of the mod as your table structure is convoluted.

Comment: That will do it! Also not sure what you mean about the table structure. I just took a MySQL course at college, apparently that qualifies me to do this kind of thing. And unfortunately I don't have any FK Constraints. I looked them up and struggled so I figured I would lay the ground work and then come back to that.

Comment: Without the foreign key constraints, you will want to use left joins and a where clause. Otherwise, it is possible that a record in the COVERED table may not have a corresponding record in the MODID table and therefore will not be listed.

Regarding the CMODID in the COVERED table, I would just leave that as MODID and have it tie back to a auto incrementing field in the MODID table. The reason being that once scaled in larger applications, it takes up less space to store the integer value and the lookups are quicker when not done on varchar fields.

Comment: I will look into that. But while I have you here do you know how to reference the column names in php with while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultc)) {
     echo (" <tr>
        <td>$row[M.MODNAME]</td>
        <td>$row[THE_DATE]</td>
        <td>$row[THE_TIME]</td>
        <td>$row[REGION]</td>
        <td>$row[CM.MODNAME]</td>
       </tr>");
    }

Comment: I would first note that the function you are using is deprecated going forward and if I were you, I'd switch over to mysqli.

That being said, I believe what you are looking for is mysql_fetch_assoc which will fetch an associative array. That function does not consider the table aliases, so you should put some AS statements in your SQL query to name the columns returned.

OR... you can do var_dump($row); in PHP and see what is in the $row variable.

Comment: Thanks! Seems Baker college is a little behind with their MySQL classes. I will look into mysqli more as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT M.MODNAME, R.THE_DATE, R.THE_TIME, C.CMODID
FROM MODID M
LEFT JOIN REQUESTS R ON R.MODID = M.MODID
AND R.COVERED = 'N';
LEFT JOIN COVERED C ON C.CMODID = M.MODID
```

Try this!

Comment: Close but no cigar this is the result: http://pastebin.com/M7438r2r and it should say Aaron K. Henderson 0000-00-00 10:00AM - 1:00PM PST TEST 3NAME